# How to define a normal distribution using tensors?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to define multivariate normal distribution with mean `[0, 0, 0, 0]` and variance - covariance matrix with only ones on diagonal. My code was:

```
import torch
import torch.distributions as td
td.Normal(loc=torch.tensor(np.zeros(4)), scale=torch.tensor(np.diag(np.repeat(1, 4)), dtype = float))
```

But I obtain Value Error:

```
ValueError: The parameter scale has invalid values
```

what should I do for proper definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`torch.distributions.Normal`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#normal) is the *univariate* normal distribution.  It handles tensor arguments by computing the results as an array of univariate distributions (using broadcasting).

For example, in the following, `normal` implements two univariate normal distributions, one with mean 0 and std. dev 1, and the other with mean 9 and std. dev. 0.25:

```
In [89]: normal = td.Normal(loc=torch.tensor([0.0, 9.0]),
    ...:                    scale=torch.tensor([1, 0.25]))
```

Draw 5 samples from each distribution:

```
In [90]: normal.rsample(sample_shape=[5])
Out[90]: 
tensor([[ 0.2460,  8.6748],
        [-0.8655,  9.0666],
        [ 0.6386,  8.7980],
        [ 0.5817,  9.1428],
        [-0.1418,  8.5777]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

For the multivariate normal distribution, use [`torch.distributions.multivariate_normal.MultivariateNormal`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#multivariatenormal).

For example,

```
In [98]: mvn = td.multivariate_normal.MultivariateNormal(
    ...:     loc=torch.zeros(4, dtype=torch.float64),
    ...:     covariance_matrix=torch.eye(4, dtype=torch.float64))

In [99]: mvn.rsample([5])
Out[99]: 
tensor([[ 0.6445,  1.3138, -2.1718,  1.1653],
        [-1.7391, -1.0428,  0.3636,  0.1957],
        [ 1.9167, -0.2738, -0.1590,  0.7170],
        [ 0.0691, -0.5422,  1.8694,  0.7470],
        [ 0.3545,  1.0585, -0.1825, -1.9955]], dtype=torch.float64)
```